# auto increment alphanumeric characters php

Tags: php, alphanumeric, automatic-properties

Is is possible to auto increment an alphanumeric number with php so it looks like:

```
AB001
AB002
...
...
BA001
...
...
ZZ001
```

This code will then need to be added to mysql, I was thinking a varchar(5).

Cheers,

Comment: Do you have any attempts at writing a function for it? It is possible, you just have to write the function the handle the incrementing.

Comment: what do you mean by "this code will then need to be added to mysql"? do you want to insert rows with a field x from `AB001` ... `ZZ001`?

Comment: @Brad: I just wanted to know if it was possible first

Comment: @ax: basically when an user signups we assign them an unique five digit code which is used for tracking on our platform

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try it and see

```
$x = 'AA998';
for($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
    echo $x++,'<br />';
}
```

**EDIT**

Reverse of letters and digits

```
$x = '000AY';
for($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
    echo $x++,'<br />';
}
```

or reversal after ZZ999

```
$x = 'ZZ998';
for($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
    $x++;
    if (strlen($x) > 5)
        $x = '000AA';
    echo $x,'<br />';
}
```

Comment: Thanks Mark, that worked. Only issue is now how would we go about reversing it so its now 000AA...999AA...000AB...999AB etc?